# Callback/Event after multiple OkHttp post request

Tags: java, android, android-service, okhttp, android-broadcastreceiver

My application has an `BroadCastReceiver`, It is programatically registered using `registerReceiver(receiver, filter)`. The code `registerReceiver(receiver, filter)` is placed in `Application` class hence it has global access.The `BroadCastReceiver` starts a `Service` that send multiple OkHttp POST requests to server. I want to unregister instance of `BroadCastReceiver` when multiple POST requests are successful. How can this be done?

MyService.java:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
     for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
       /....Multiple POST Requests..../
     }

     Callback/Event(){ execute unregisterReceiver();}
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {

  }
}
```

MyReciever.java:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
  }
}
```

Comment: What have *you* tried that's not working? Anything?

Comment: I want to implement some kind of Callback() which will be executed when multiple post requests (Which are asynchronous) are sucessful.

Comment: But what have you done yourself. Before asking someone else to do the work you get paid for?

Comment: I tried searching for ways to synchronize (one after another) these requests... Dint find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it by simply using a counter variable.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

 int counter;
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
  counter = size ;
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    /....Multiple POST Requests..../

    OnResponse: 
    counter-- 
    if(counter ==0){ 
      execute unregisterReceiver();
      }

   }

 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {

   }
 }
```